# Не принимает конфигурацию WebMvcConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

На компе всё работает, на ноуте выдаёт следующую ошибку
[image: скрин]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`WebMvcConfig`

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    }
}
```

[image: sdk]

Answer (score 2):

Метод `WebMvcConfigurer#getMessageCodesResolver()`помечен как `default`, что означает, что он имеет реализацию "по умолчанию". Такая фича в интерфейсах и абстрактных классах работает только с Java версии 8+. Следовательно, если у вас IDE требует реализации `default` метода, то в проекте установлена Java версии меньше 8. Т.е. надо пойти в настройки проекта и установить версию Java 8 или больше.

Comment: стоит java 11 (11.0.4)

Comment: @Surv, видимо не везде или не там) Покажите скрины настроек проекта `ProjectSetting` -> `Project`, `Module` и `PlatformSettings` -> `SDKs`

Comment: @Surv для удобства понимания, посмотри данный вопрос [по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878045/errorjava-invalid-source-release-8-in-intellij-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил скрин

Comment: @Surv, у вас на скрине только одна вкладка из 3. Покажите ещё `ProjectSetting -> Project`и `ProjectSetting -> Module`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил

Comment: @Surv, странно... А `java -version` что выводит?

Comment: @Surv, и покажите конфиг сборщика (maven или gradle) - там тоже можно прописывать версию Java. И попробуйте вместо 11 поставить 8.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ```java -version``` выдаёт следующее 
```java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)```

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Поставил всё на 8ую, ничего не изменилось

Comment: терь ругается, что нужна 11ая java. странно, что в консоли ток 8ую видит, ша попробую переустановить 11ую

Comment: вроде устанавливается, в IDE отображается, но в консоли винды не определяется, что java вообещ есть, ну и проблема осталась

Comment: @Surv, а какую систему дял сборки используете? Maven или Gradle? Попробуйте ещё и там прописать версию. Например, для Maven можно вот так: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Создал новый проект, подкорректировал pom.xml(обновил версии), и скопировал содержимое старого проекта. Всё работает, всем спасибо.